# JPA entity field that is not mapping db column but is obtained by query

Tags: jpa

I have 2 db tables: tree and leaf. It is obviously one to many relationship. I want to have a leavesCount field in the Tree entity - it should be not persisted (@Transient) but also obtained by query every time the entity is loaded into context. Is it possible to achieve?

I know I could just make @OneToMany and get the collection's size but I'm really intrested in the query approach.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a named query, and just execute it when required.

Otherwise you could make the field persistent, and ensure you update it every time a leaf is added.

Comment: The thing is that I cannot modify the db structure. I will try to elaborate - every leaf has some properties describing it's state, e.g. isInfested or isGreen. Now I have generic grid which takes the entity class, and I have to display the number of green and noninfested leaves for every tree. How would you approach this?

Comment: I would handle this with a query.

Answer (score 0):

Queries are used to interact with the database. If you mark a property as @Transient, then this property will not be persisted in the database and then you can't ask the database about this property. It's like it doesn't exist for JPA. So you can't put your transient property in your queries. TBH I never tried to reach a transient property in a query so I can't be 100% sure but anyway you're not supposed to do so and therefore it shouldn't work.